# Error loading transactions/ Will not connect wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I can load the GSafe wallet. My SAFE tokens appear on the assets list, but not in the bar at top right. My MM wallet will not connect, but will connect to other dApps. I can not interact with the SAFE dApp.

This is the error in console: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://app.safe.global/transactions/6410db63dad581f6.css.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Also: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I can't find troubleshooting for this. Can anyone suggest actions?

Thanks

Comment: When I click the link I posted above, it connects me automatically and the problem is "solved." <---- no idea why tho. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.